# Putting line marks on Slider

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I Want to put line marks like the image below when I make a right click on the slider. Can this be done with javafx Slider? If yes, then how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Wrap the slider in a group.
- Draw a line across the slider at the right position and add it to the group. (If you want use the opacity property to make the line transparent.)
- Use the visible-property to switch the line on and off as reaction to the right click event on the slider.

A code expample:

```
Slider slider = new Slider(0,100,50);
slider.setLayoutY(5);

Line line = new line();
line.setStrokeWidth(2);
line.setStroke(Color.RED);
line.setOpacity(0.3);
line.setStartX(50);
line.setEndX(50);
line.setStartY(4);
line.setEndY(21);
line.setVisible(true);

Group group = new Group(slider, line);
```